# Book about a man who repeatedly dies by fire and is reincarnated through the ages

Tags: story-identification, books, reincarnation

It was about 30-odd years ago perhaps, but I read an amazing book that starts in an ancient (perhaps Neolithic) period and recounts the story of a man who repeatedly dies and is reincarnated, again and again (always dying by fire, as I recall).  The thing I remember most about it is how the language evolves through the book from very simple to sophisticated.

I've been trying to find it, but I've had no joy... can anyone help please?

Comment: One of Piers Anthony's [Geodyssey series](https://www.goodreads.com/series/40497-geodyssey) maybe? The timing fits though I don't recall any of the books exactly fitting your description.

Comment: The more detail you can add, the better answers you'll get.  Can you remember anything specific about any of the man's lives, for instance?

Answer (score 4):

It's not a great match to the focus on language in your question, but there is such a character in Avram Davidson's *The Phoenix and the Mirror* (1969).  The setting of the book corresponds to the Mediterranean in the first century BCE, but the implied back-story of the titular Phoenix would fit your description.  The protagonist Vergil Magus is loosely based on the Roman poet Virgil (author of the *Aeneid*) reimagined as an alchemical scholar in an alternate history Roman empire where such arcane lore holds truth.

Answer (score 2):

Possibly *[Phoenix Rising: The Legend Begins](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/13281688-phoenix-rising)* by Ron Richardson. Though it was published in 2011, not the *"30-odd years ago"* you estimated.

[image: Cover of "Phoenix Rising: The Legend Begins" by Ron Richardson. The cover shows a dark background with something burning brightly.]

***DISCLAIMER:*** I haven't read this one properly - I saw it in one of those "Little Free Libraries", had a quick look, but wasn't interested until I saw this question and realised it could be the answer. So I'm skimming it as I write to find the relevant information, and will return it tomorrow.

(As an aside, I'm not impressed with the book. I'd rate it two out of five. Or less.)

> starts in an ancient (perhaps Neolithic) period

Not as ancient as that - from the foreword:

> *My story starts a few years before Caesar's first attempt at invasion.*

You said:

> a man who repeatedly dies and is reincarnated, again and again (always dying by fire, as I recall).

Luka Phoenix dies only a few seconds after his birth. He has a glowing aura surrounding him, and the local druid takes this as a bad omen. The same druid immediately stabs him through the heart.

He regenerates shortly after, and has the glowing aura again for a short time after this. Upon his return to life the wound is mostly healed, but there is a visible scar.

Later on, he's killed by a squad of Roman soldiers. Again, it's a violent death. He's cut several times with a knife, and run over by horses to break every bone in his body. The soldiers then leave him for dead. A bolt of lightning appears to trigger his rejeuvenation, and again he finds himself returned to life with regenerative energy healing his wounds and the glowing aura around his body.

Prior to that, he's killed in a battle between his tribe and Roman soldiers. It's the same sort of magical recovery from death and complete healing of severe physical wounds. This time, there's an accident after his regeneration which sets a tent on fire.

Having been told about the legend of the phoenix, Luka begins using an image of a phoenix on his shield soon after this.

When he dies from an illness later on, the glow is a white glow, and this time his face and body change quite significantly. Rather like a Time Lord regeneration.

Throughout all this, Luka's total lifespan across all regenerations is a lot longer than that of a normal human, andd he doesn't appear to age past 25. He's alive at the time of Vercingetorix's final stand, and has travelled to Gaul to fight alongside him. Many, many years later, so much time has passed (and he has aged so little) that he has to pretend it was his grandfather at that battle. His regenerative abilities also improve, with wounds healing immediately after being inflicted. Later on, attacks just bounce off without wounding him, although the glowing aura still occurs.

In the final chapter of the book, Luka has long ago returned to Britain. The troops under his command have almost been wiped out, after encountering an entire Roman legion. Luka now does something which he seems to instinctively know will kill him. He shoots a flaming arrow into the air, where it is hit by lightning. A ball of fire shoots down from the impact and hits Luka. Then:

> *Across the sky there appeared a huge phoenix in all its glory which then shot to earth and vanished.*

There is no sign of the body - as far as the Romans can tell - but when they search the area, they find a small baby with a scar. Luka's regeneration *this* time is much more like a reincarnation, but for some reason the scar left on him as a baby is still present. The final words of the book suggest that he has no memory of his previous life and his hatred of the Romans, and it's explicitly stated that he grows up and becomes a Roman himself.

In fact, I've just done some googling and it turns out the story continues in a sequel. [Phoenix Rising: The Roman Years](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/21339291-the-roman-years).

[image: Cover of "Phoenix Rising: The Roman Years" by Ron Richardson. The cover shows a man in Roman armor crouching behind a large Roman shield, emblazoned with a phoenix.]

In this, Luka's second incarnation has grown up to become Lucius Pontilius, an extremely high-ranking Roman centurion (a [primus pilus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primus_pilus).) During the book, he apparently starts having flashbacks and remembering some of his previous life.

Answer (score 1):

Could this be [Jorge Luis Borges](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jorge_Luis_Borges) short story  "[The Circular Ruins](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Circular_Ruins)",

This is a story of a man who travels down a river and falls asleep to dream and thereby create his disciple/son. He spends some time in doing so and makes two attempts of different methods, and finally succeeds in creating the person. He then hears from the locals who come to worship/pay tribute to him that his son is able to walk through fire unharmed. The dreamer is then interrupted by a forest fire, which burns through his living place but leaves him unharmed, and with the knowledge that he has also been created in a similar manner to his son.

Answer (score 0):

Bit of a long shot as I don't think it matches your main description of the same person being reincarnated, but could it be Alan Moore's *[Voice of the Fire](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voice_of_the_Fire)*?

It does feature language evolving over time, starting with a very basic version in an ancient period, [which evolves](https://www.page45.com/store/Voice-Of-The-Fire-25th-Anniversary-Edition-sc.html) as the stories move through the eras. All the stories are set around the same location through the ages, and I think there are also references to previous events in later stories, which might contribute towards you remembering it as one person being reincarnated.

Fire also features quite centrally throughout.

Published in 1996 so the timeline fits.